# Unable to get the MATCH property of the WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vba

I've read all the other posts about this but still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  To minimize confounders, I've reduced my spreadsheet to the minimum:

- Sheet1 has 2 dates, one in B1 and one in B2
- Sheet2 has the same 2 dates in A1 and A2

My code is:

```
Public Sub GetPymtEffDate()
Dim x As Variant
Dim LookupValue As Variant
Dim LookupArray As Range

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
LookupValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
Set LookupArray = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:a2")
MsgBox LookupValue

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(LookupValue, LookupArray, 1)
MsgBox x

End Sub
```

The idea is that if the ActiveCell is on row 1 of Sheet1, for example, it'll go find that same date on Sheet2.  The first MsgBox works fine, but it gives an error on the Match function, even though I know the date is there.

What am I doing wrong?  (is there an icon for beating my head against a wall?)

Comment: Typically you get that error if match doesn't find the value you're looking for.  Can you use MATCH() on the worksheet with those same inputs and get a hit?

Comment: Yes, if I put `=MATCH(B1,Sheet2!A$1:A$2)` into  D1 and D2 on Sheet1, it returns the correct position of the dates on Sheet2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LookupValue` type is Variant/Date.
Match looks for values (unformated, for example  30.04.2015 is just 42124).

Try `CLng` function. Like this:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(LookupValue), LookupArray, 1)
```

Comment: Great!  That did it.  Thanks.  Should I always convert dates to Long?  Or is there another best practice when working with dates?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but in my experience Match() has issues with dates.

You can instead use a reference to the cell instead of its value:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim v, c As Range

    'this works
    Debug.Print Application.Match(Range("D3"), Range("B3:B4"), 1)

    'and this works
    Set c = Range("D3")
    Debug.Print Application.Match(c, Range("B3:B4"), 1)

    'this doesn't work
    v = Range("D3").Value
    Debug.Print Application.Match(v, Range("B3:B4"), 1)

End Sub
```

My test dates were on the same sheet but that shouldn't make any difference.